# When to purposefully lose trophies

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is there any benefit to purposefully losing attacks? For example, I've been trying to get more resources with the Barch army, but I've noticed I haven't been doing so well recently. Maybe it's because the higher the trophy count, the harder the bases you attack are, so could it be a solution to throw some attacks and just drop a single barbarian, then end the game?

Since the treasury is the best protected resource when your base is raided, I always try to get 5 stars so loot is added to it. This does seem to increase my trophy count, even when I'm trying to focus on resources.

Comment: How many trophies do you have

Comment: @Cameron.C 1670

Comment: I actually think this is a pretty decent question. Intentionally dropping trophies isn't intuitive, especially to new players, since trophies are an indicator of "success" within the game. So, I don't understand the downvotes here.

Comment: @Ellesedill, just speculation, but until I altered the question, the context sounded like OP wanted users opinions. Opinion based questions are off topic, and at the time, this question was actually marked for closure. Generally this also attracts down voting.

Comment: @Timelord64 I think anything that pertains to strategy is in a sense a matter of opinion. We have lots of questions about attack strategies and they don't get closed as opinion based.

Comment: They don't deliberately ask for an opinion, either. I agree that strategy requires a *small* degree of opinion, but it is intentionally asking for an opinion that makes the question **primarily** opinion based, and off topic.

Comment: I notice it was more how it could be interpreted, but the down votes may have also stemmed from poor spelling and grammar. We tend to to expect better English, here.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Yes it is a valid technique to use, even after the 5 star loot bonus update. To lose trophies, if you have a hero, drop the hero and quit instantly, that way you don't have to remake a barbarian each time; otherwise, just dropping a barb is a good way to do it. If your hero isn't hurt he will be back for the next raid without any down time.

**Longer Explanation**

Purposefully losing trophies is a valid technique and should be employed in certain situations. Since higher level bases and more serious players tend to have more trophies, losing trophies will help you encounter more casual players. Especially if you are using a weak army like barch and having difficulty, it may be a good idea.

You are also correct that since the addition of the 5 star bonus, and bonuses being made larger in the recent update, it is less appealing to lose trophies; nevertheless it can still be quite a good strategy. One real world example is that now I'm a TH9 around 3000+ trophies, at this level I see mostly TH10s while 'nexting' that I don't want to attack, and the TH9s I do see have maxed bases, higher heroes, good layouts, and usually don't have much loot. On my friends account, he stays at 2600 trophies and the attackers and defenders are much weaker, and it is generally easier to find a base to attack, however, he does not receive the higher star bonus and raid loot bonus, so it's a trade off.

To find a good trophy count may take some trial and error, as it will vary with your town hall, troop and hero upgrades. Also, these trophy counts will change over time as the player pool naturally will shift a little bit up or down, so don't expect to stay at one range forever. Supercell will inevitably release more patches changing farming and matchmaking that will alter trophy counts as well, so keep on eye on updates!

To lose trophies, if you have a hero, drop the hero and quit instantly, that way you don't have to remake a barbarian each time; otherwise, just dropping a barb is a good way to do it. If your hero isn't hurt he will be back for the next raid without any down time.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of losing trophies is the fact that the lower your league go the easier the attacks and defenses will be for you.

Comment: What's the easiest way of loosing trophies? just dropping a single barb near an elixor collector?